# vhdl multiple entity with 1 architecture

Tags: vhdl

I would like to know if I can use multiple entities (different ports) with a single architecture (different ports will be accessed using generate statements based on a generic) all in 1 file but have a configuration that maps the architecture to the correct entity at compile time.

My issue is that I have code where 3/4 of the code is the same and part of it is different because the fpga that the code is used with has different pin mappings and I don't want to be maintaining multiple files whenever I change code. Hopefully this makes sense

pseudo code:

```
entity e_1 is
 generic(
  entityType : string := '1'
 );
 port1 : in std_logic
);

entity e_2 is
 generic(
  entityType : string := '2'
 );
 port2 : in std_logic
);

architecture a of e_1 is
begin

 L_1 : if entityType = "1" generate
  port1 <= '1';
 end generate L_1;

 L_2 : if entityType = "2" generate
  port2 <= '1';
 end generate L_2;

end architecture a;
```

Amish

Comment: Write an entity/architecture that has all the ports you need. Instantiate this in another entity/architecture for each FPGA, connecting up the ports that one uses.

Comment: interesting. I will try it our and see if that works. Thanks for the insight

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks @BrianDrummond